# Yocto Dunfell instalar chromium o firefox

Tags: yocto

Necesito añadir a mi aplicación en Yocto Dunfell un browser. He intentado con chromium-x11 y firefox (meta-broswer-master) y siempre obtengo errores con bitbake.
Podrías ayudame a completar la instalación.
Gracias

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cómo lo intentaste y qué errores salieron? Las preguntas sin el cóödigo, los mensajes de error y demás detalles no son buenas preguntas. Por favor ve a [edit] y completa tu pregunta

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.